# que significa este error 2021 estoy conectando un contrato para slash payment

Tags: codeigniter-4

string(17) "{"errors":[2021]}" Error: No se pudo obtener la URL desde la respuesta JSON. Detalles: {"errors":[2021]}Error: No se pudo obtener la URL desde la respuesta JSON.